# How to solve "Integrity check failed for 'websocket-driver'" error when installing dependencies?

Tags: websocket, next.js, yarnpkg

I tried to upload my Next.js application to Vercel and during the deployment time Vercel threw an error message.

[image]

Then I tried to reinstall my yarn package and the installation did not get completed my command terminal threw the same error about websocket.

[image]

How to resolve the error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try clearing the cache and updating the checksums in the `yarn.lock` file by running the following commands.

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install --update-checksums
```

You could also try deleting the `yarn.lock` file altogether and re-run `yarn install`.

Answer (score 1):

check if there's anything cached in `~/.config/yarn`.

`rm -rf ~/.config/yarn` solved my problem.