# Getting "Integrity check failed" error when installing dependencies with yarn

Tags: dependencies, hadoop-yarn, integrity

I am trying to install dependencies in one of my project. On 'yarn install' command, I am getting below error.

> "Integrity check failed for '@fmvilas/pseudo-yaml-ast'(Computed integrity doesn't match our records)"

Can someone please suggest, what can be done to resolve this error and install this package succesfully?

I tried to remove this particular package from dependencies in yarn.lock file, and yarn install worked fine. But yes,I am getting error when trying to run the app.
So I a tried to add only this package i.e, command: **yarn add @fmvilas/pseudo-yaml-ast**, again got same Integrity check failed error.

I tried following this link - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027206/how-to-solve-integrity-check-failed-for-websocket-driver-error-when-installi](https://stackoverflow.com), but no luck.